# how to write a print method like python?

Tags: java, printing, casting

I want to write a method in java, just like I used it in python,but it will print address intead of num:

the following is the code:

I can use print(1,2,3) or print(obj[]),but I can not print(int[])
when I use integer[] num={1,2,3,4,5};the output is correct

how to print(int[])  like python?

```
  public class Print {


        public static void print() {
            System.out.println();
        }   


        public static void print(Object... obj) {
            for(Object c:obj){
                System.out.print(c);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        public static void print(Object obj) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] num={1,2,3,4,5};
            print(num);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the output you are looking for?

Comment: print(num);  output: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: just like print method in python

Answer (score 1):

To display the array content, you could use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The reason that you are seeing an "address" is that the primitive array `int[]` is an Object but not an `Object[]` as used in your first `print` method. Therefore

```
public static void print(Object obj)
```

is called.

To get your first method to work, you would have to use something like:

```
public static void print(int[] nums {
    for (int num : nums) {
        System.out.print(num);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

or if the above output format is acceptable:

```
public static void print(int[] nums) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

Comment: I want write it in print method

Comment: 'int[]' is single object not object array, so causes your third method to be called. Have given some suggestions for `print` in my update. :)

Answer (score 0):

`print(Object... obj)` is basically `print(Object[] obj)`. If you don't pass an `Object[]`, `print(Object obj)` will be used instead. `int` is a primitive and does **not** inherit from `Object` so your `int[]` is **not** an `Object[]`. You can either use the wrapper-class `Integer` and create an `Integer[]` or you have to implement `print(int[] ints)`.

`print(1,2,3)` works because the arguments are automatically converted to `Integer`s.

Comment: @user1648947 That's actually right: Every **class** inherits from Object. However, types like `int` aren't classes, they are **primitives**.